# Time Picker with 00:00:00 AM/PM format with seconds in android

Tags: android

In my Time Tracking android project I want TimePicker with seconds field. After googling so much I did not find any solution & in last  I make my custom TimePicker for android which gives time values in 00:00:00 AM/PM format. I think this code is helpful to android developers so I upload this code to Stack.

**main.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <Button 
            android:text="Time"
            android:id="@+id/time_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            />
        <TextView               
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/time_txt"                 
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            />            
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**customdialog.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
         >            
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            >
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/clock"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/coggl_logo"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
            />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/actualtime"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clock"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="00:00:00 AM"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"       
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
            />           
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/plus1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
        />
        <Button 
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/plus2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plus1"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
        />
        <Button 
        android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
              android:id="@+id/plus3"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plus2"


            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
             />
           <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
              android:id="@+id/hours"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/plus1"
           android:text="00"
            android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
             />
           <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hours"
              android:id="@+id/minutes"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/plus2"
            android:text="00"
            android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
             />
           <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minutes"
              android:id="@+id/seconds"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/plus3"
            android:text="00"
            android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
             />
           <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seconds"
              android:id="@+id/am"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/plus3"
           android:text="AM"
            android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
             />
           <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seconds"
              android:id="@+id/pm"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/plus3"
               android:text="PM"
            android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
             />
           <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
              android:id="@+id/minus1"
              android:layout_below="@+id/hours"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
             />
           <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minus1"
              android:id="@+id/minus2"
              android:layout_below="@+id/minutes"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
             />
           <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minus2"
              android:id="@+id/minus3"
              android:layout_below="@+id/seconds"
              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
             />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_below="@+id/second"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        >
        <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/set"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
             android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:textColor="#000000"
            />  
            <Button android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/set"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
             android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#000000"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**CustomTimePickerDialogActivity.Java**

```
        public class CustomTimePickerDialogActivity extends Activity {
            TextView tv;
            Button time_btn;
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_txt);
                time_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.time_btn);
                time_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         showTimePickerDialog();
                    }
                });
            }
            public void showTimePickerDialog()
            {
                final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(CustomTimePickerDialogActivity.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
                final TextView actualtime=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.actualtime);
                final Button hourplus=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.plus1);
                Button minplus=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.plus2);
                Button secplus=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.plus3);
                Button hourminus=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.minus1);
                Button minminus=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.minus2);
                Button secminus=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.minus3);
                final Button am=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.am);
                final Button pm=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.pm);
                final Button hourvalue=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.hours);
                final Button minvalue=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.minutes);
                final Button secvalue=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.seconds);
                Button set=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.set);
                Button cancel=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                dialog.show();
                 Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                    String am_pm;
                      int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                      int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                      int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                      String curhour=String.valueOf(hour);
                      String curmin=String.valueOf(minute);
                      String cursec=String.valueOf(seconds);
                      if(curhour.length()== 1)
                      {
                          curhour="0"+curhour; 
                      }
                      if(curmin.length()== 1)
                      {
                          curmin="0"+curmin; 
                      }
                      if(cursec.length()== 1)
                      {
                          cursec="0"+cursec; 
                      }
                      if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
                      am_pm = "AM";
                      else
                      am_pm = "PM";


                if(am_pm.equalsIgnoreCase("AM"))
                {
                    am.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    pm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    am.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if(curhour.equalsIgnoreCase("00"))
                {
                    curhour="12";
                }
                 actualtime.setText(curhour+":"+curmin+":"+cursec+" "+am_pm);
                  hourvalue.setText(curhour);
                  minvalue.setText(curmin);
                  secvalue.setText(cursec);
                am.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        pm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        am.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        String tmphour=hourvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpmin=minvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpsec=secvalue.getText().toString();
                        actualtime.setText(tmphour+":"+tmpmin+":"+tmpsec+" "+"PM");
                    }
                });
                pm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        am.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        pm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        String tmphour=hourvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpmin=minvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpsec=secvalue.getText().toString();
                        actualtime.setText(tmphour+":"+tmpmin+":"+tmpsec+" "+"AM");
                    }
                });
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String tmphour=hourvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpmin=minvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpsec=secvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpam_pm="";

                        if(am.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="AM";
                        }
                        if(pm.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)   
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="PM";
                        }
                        actualtime.setText(tmphour+":"+tmpmin+":"+tmpsec+" "+tmpam_pm);

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        tv.setText(tmphour+":"+tmpmin+":"+tmpsec+" "+tmpam_pm);
                    }
                });
                hourplus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String tmphour=hourvalue.getText().toString();
                        int curdisplayhr=Integer.parseInt(tmphour);
                        int finaldisplayhr = 0;
                        if(curdisplayhr<12)
                        {
                            finaldisplayhr=curdisplayhr+1;
                        }
                        else if(curdisplayhr==12)
                        {
                            finaldisplayhr=1;
                        }
                        String finalhr=String.valueOf(finaldisplayhr);
                        if(finalhr.length()==1)
                        {
                            finalhr="0"+finalhr;
                        }
                        hourvalue.setText(finalhr);

                        String tmpmin=minvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpsec=secvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpam_pm="";
                        if(am.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="AM";
                        }
                        if(pm.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="PM";
                        }
                        actualtime.setText(finalhr+":"+tmpmin+":"+tmpsec+" "+tmpam_pm);
                    }
                });
                minplus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String tmpmin=minvalue.getText().toString();
                        int curdisplaymin=Integer.parseInt(tmpmin);
                        int finaldisplaymin = 0;
                        if(curdisplaymin<59)
                        {
                            finaldisplaymin=curdisplaymin+1;
                        }
                        else if(curdisplaymin==59)
                        {
                            finaldisplaymin=0;
                        }
                        String finalmin=String.valueOf(finaldisplaymin);
                        if(finalmin.length()==1)
                        {
                            finalmin="0"+finalmin;
                        }
                        minvalue.setText(finalmin);
                        String tmphour=hourvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpsec=secvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpam_pm="";
                        if(am.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="AM";
                        }
                        if(pm.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="PM";
                        }
                        actualtime.setText(tmphour+":"+finalmin+":"+tmpsec+" "+tmpam_pm);
                    }
                });
                secplus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String tmpsec=secvalue.getText().toString();
                        int curdisplaysec=Integer.parseInt(tmpsec);
                        int finaldisplaysec = 0;
                        if(curdisplaysec<59)
                        {
                            finaldisplaysec=curdisplaysec+1;
                        }
                        else if(curdisplaysec==59)
                        {
                            finaldisplaysec=0;
                        }
                        String finalsec=String.valueOf(finaldisplaysec);
                        if(finalsec.length()==1)
                        {
                            finalsec="0"+finalsec;
                        }
                        secvalue.setText(finalsec);
                        String tmphour=hourvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpmin=minvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpam_pm="";
                        if(am.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="AM";
                        }
                        if(pm.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="PM";
                        }
                        actualtime.setText(tmphour+":"+tmpmin+":"+finalsec+" "+tmpam_pm);
                    }
                });
                hourminus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String tmphour=hourvalue.getText().toString();
                        int curdisplayhr=Integer.parseInt(tmphour);
                        int finaldisplayhr = 0;

                        if(curdisplayhr==1)
                        {
                            finaldisplayhr=12;
                        }
                        else if(curdisplayhr>1||curdisplayhr<13)
                        {
                            finaldisplayhr=curdisplayhr-1;
                        }
                        String finalhr=String.valueOf(finaldisplayhr);
                        if(finalhr.length()==1)
                        {
                            finalhr="0"+finalhr;
                        }
                        hourvalue.setText(finalhr);

                        String tmpmin=minvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpsec=secvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpam_pm="";
                        if(am.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="AM";
                        }
                        if(pm.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="PM";
                        }
                        actualtime.setText(finalhr+":"+tmpmin+":"+tmpsec+" "+tmpam_pm);
                    }
                });
                minminus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String tmpmin=minvalue.getText().toString();
                        int curdisplaymin=Integer.parseInt(tmpmin);
                        int finaldisplaymin = 0;
                         if(curdisplaymin==0)
                        {
                            finaldisplaymin=59;
                        }
                         else 
                            {
                                finaldisplaymin=curdisplaymin-1;
                            }

                        String finalmin=String.valueOf(finaldisplaymin);
                        if(finalmin.length()==1)
                        {
                            finalmin="0"+finalmin;
                        }
                        minvalue.setText(finalmin);
                        String tmphour=hourvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpsec=secvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpam_pm="";
                        if(am.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="AM";
                        }
                        if(pm.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="PM";
                        }
                        actualtime.setText(tmphour+":"+finalmin+":"+tmpsec+" "+tmpam_pm);
                    }
                });
                secminus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String tmpsec=secvalue.getText().toString();
                        int curdisplaysec=Integer.parseInt(tmpsec);
                        int finaldisplaysec = 0;
                        if(curdisplaysec==0)
                        {
                            finaldisplaysec=59;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            finaldisplaysec=curdisplaysec-1;
                        }
                        String finalsec=String.valueOf(finaldisplaysec);
                        if(finalsec.length()==1)
                        {
                            finalsec="0"+finalsec;
                        }
                        secvalue.setText(finalsec);
                        String tmphour=hourvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpmin=minvalue.getText().toString();
                        String tmpam_pm="";
                        if(am.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="AM";
                        }
                        if(pm.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            tmpam_pm="PM";
                        }
                        actualtime.setText(tmphour+":"+tmpmin+":"+finalsec+" "+tmpam_pm);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but please put it up the question answer format and accept it. This way it wont figure as unanswered so people waste time on answering something that is answered but it's also much easier to read through for users common with stackoverflow question-answer style.

Comment: Same thing, Stack Overflow is not the right place for that. Create a public repo in GitHub and not only it will stop unfitting here but more people will benefit from it in GH.